# Attach Photo to Facebook Page Post Error 324

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to attach a photo to a scheduled Facebook Page post.   But Keep getting the error "(#324) Requires upload file".  The Token is correct and the scheduled post shows up on the Page but not the image.   This looks correct but am not sure.

```
 var fbClient = new FacebookClient(pageToken);
        var whenToPub = ((DateTimeOffset)DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        dynamic result = fbClient.Post(pageId+"/feed", new { published = false, message = "This is Just a test post", scheduled_publish_time = whenToPub });
        string postId = result.id;


        var info = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        info.Add("message", "test photo");
        info.Add("src", imageURL);
        var result2 = fbClient.Post("/" + postId + "/photos", info);
```

Comment: Can you point to where it is documented that this could be done by posting to `/post-id/photos`?

Comment: I had read a post but looking at the documentation it looks likes you can't add a photo to a post.  You can upload an image or make a Post.

Comment: You can upload a photo first, and then specify that photo (via id) as an attachment for a post.